# Resize Scrolling Div to browser height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My scrolling div wont stretch the height of its parent container when resizing the browser or when toggling a button that adds an extra space on the top.

**AUG 27 UPDATE**
http://jsfiddle.net/ursp39s9/

The following jfiddle contains a code by **ctwheels** that has been modified to fit my needs, and as a result I've discovered the issue has to do with a show/hide button filter (Code provided below)

This button adds an extra space at the bottom when the button is pressed, and then dissapears when it's pressed again. However, this seems to be causing issues with the resizeable scrolling div container thats suppose to stretch to 100% height and width to fill the entire parent container. Instead I get a whitespace at the bottom all the time.

So please take a look at my jsfiddle, and see if you can help me fix this issue. Thanks!

**Here's the problematic HTML:**

```
<div id="feed-content">

<div id="networkfeed" class="feedpagetab activefeed">

        <input type="checkbox" id="filterbutton" role="button">
    <label for="filterbutton" onclick=""><span class="filterswitch">Show Me</span><span class="filterswitch">Hide Me</span> </label>     
<br /><br />

<div class="borderline"></div>


<section class="filtercontent">

</section><!--Filtercontent ends here-->
```

**And the CSS:**

```
/*----- Show me Button-----*/
.filtercontent {
    margin: 0;border-bottom:#000 solid 1px; 
    padding: 0; height:170px; margin-top:5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.feedpagetab > section:first-of-type {
    float: right;
    width: 62.5%;
}

.feedpagetab > section:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.feedpagetab {
    -webkit-transition: .125s linear;
    -moz-transition: .125s linear;
    -ms-transition: .125s linear;
    -o-transition: .125s linear;
    transition: .125s linear;
}

#filterbutton[type=checkbox] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0; 
    position: absolute;
}

[for="filterbutton"] {
    position: absolute;
    top:4px;
    padding: 0;
    left: 5%;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px; font-weight:bold;
        color: #555;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #DDD;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Sans Serif";
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    background: #EEE;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F9F9F9), color-stop(100%,#DDD));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%,#DDD 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%,#DDD 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%,#DDD 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#F9F9F9', endColorstr='#DDD',GradientType=0 );
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%,#DDD 100%); 
}

[for="filterbutton"]:hover {
   color: #444444;font-weight:bold;
    border-color: #BBB;
    background: #CCC;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F9F9F9), color-stop(100%,#CCC));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%,#CCC 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%,#CCC 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%,#CCC 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#F9F9F9', endColorstr='#CCC',GradientType=0 );
}

[for="filterbutton"] span.filterswitch:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked {color:#FFA317;}


#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .filtercontent {
    display: block; 
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%; 
}

#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="filterbutton"] span.filterswitch:first-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;  
}


#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="filterbutton"] span.filterswitch:last-of-type { color:#3CC; 
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}

.borderline { width:100%; border-bottom:#000 solid 1px; height:0px;}


.filtercontent { margin-left:29%; }
```

Comment: Why are you making it so hard on yourself... If html had errors, you'd have a lot. Why not do the layout like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4Lgqfdj1/

Comment: That jsfiddle you provided doenst contain a div with scrollbar that fills up the entire parent container and resizes according to browser or toggled on content. Can you please add it to you jfiddle. I just want to grasp the concept and the code behind it. ALso my code has some errors, but not big enough errors to prevent a scrolling fluid div from functioning.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lgqfdj1/1/

Comment: The parent div doest not cover the entire available space, and the div with the scrollbar does not resize according to the height of the browser. So can you please add it to the fiddle?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/4Lgqfdj1/3/ It isn't perfect, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Hey, sorry it took so long to respond, but I'm still working on the project. I've indentified the problem and have created a new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ursp39s9/ Check my edited post for more info.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ursp39s9/1/

Comment: It's almost there I've updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ursp39s9/2/ The issue is still in the toggle button. The scrolling div must fill the entire conatiner, but there seems to be a white space at the bottom caused by the following divs: filtercontent #filterbutton .feedpagetab.

Comment: Like that? http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/ursp39s9/3/

Comment: There is still a white space at the bottom, and when you click on the button it pushes the scrolling div to the bottom removing the down arrow. This is essentially the same problem I had before.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/ursp39s9/4/

Comment: No, that made it worse. Now when you click the toggle button or resize it, it stays small. I want to stretch the div the full height of the parent container so you only see the green scrolling div. Even if you press the show button it should resize accordingly and take up the remaining height.

Comment: Then I'm not exactly sure what you're asking :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fkvftff2/ I've forked the jsfiddle. I'm almost there. If you check the fiddle now it stays in place as I resize it with the exception of a 2-3 px margin at the bottom. However, when I stretch the div up, and press the button to show and then again to hide. The hidden content space moves to the bottom. I want to get rid of all the white space at the bottom.